# Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am wondering if there is any proof of this:

> If $f$ is a Mobius mapping, then $$\frac{\frac{f(a)-f(c)}{f(a)-f(d)}}{\frac{f(b)-f(c)}{f(b)-f(d)}} = \frac{\frac{a-c}{a-d}}{\frac{b-c}{b-d}}$$

Proof where you put $f(z)=\frac{Az+B}{Cz+D}$ and deal with long rational expressions does not interest me.

Comment: "Proof... deal with long rational expressions does not interest me."  Really, if you hate math, then this is not the place for you.

Comment: Where did you find this result? Did the reference actually prove this by bruteforce?

Comment: @RonGordon I don't think it's unreasonable to ask for a cleaner and more elegant solution, right?

Comment: @JefLaga: Of course not.  But to take the attitude "I hate doing things out - one of you peons do my work for me" comes across as a poor attitude.  Considering we are here because we love math, I'd rather not deal with such attitudes.

Comment: @RonGordon OK I understand. I just thought the OP might have formulated this maybe a little too radical, but was genuinely interested in a better solution :-)

Comment: Perhaps somewhat perversely, I'm willing to give the OP credit for having "context" by considering/describing the plug-and-chug approach, even if they reject pursuing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall (or note) that every Mobius transformation is a combination of mappings of the following types:

1. $z \mapsto z+\alpha$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$
2. $z\mapsto \alpha z$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$
3. $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$

Now note that your identity holds for every type of mapping above, now conclude.